# Automapper map to custom two object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have got one generic list and I want to mapping this generic list to another type of generic list(BatchModel to Batch). But I have got some conditions before  mapping two this object like that;

```
CrudTypes crudTypes(Enum)

List<BatchModel> batchModels;
             var models = batchModels.Select(p => new Batch
                {
                    BatchId = p.BatchId,
                    Id = p.Id,                   
                    CompleteTimeOnServer = crudTypes.Equals(CrudTypes.Insert) ? DateTime.Now : p.CompleteTimeOnServer,                    
                    SyncRetryCount = p.SyncRetryCount
                }).ToList();
```

How can I do this mapping in automapper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to do this, using `BeforeMap` in AutoMapper (see http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html).
Their own example:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { 
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .BeforeMap((src, dest) => src.Value = src.Value + 10)
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Name = "John");
});
```

And so you could rewrite this to extract the correct set (by your conditions) map as usual.